# Chrome extension with news ticker

Tags: plugins, cross-browser, browser-extension, news-ticker, crossrider

Hello fellow programmers. I want to make a browser extension that will put a news ticker at the top of every page.I want to use the code here (as it will make coding easier): http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html. I would like to develop with crossrider. I am, admittedly, not very good with javascript but I deffinatley know enough to make a simple app like this. I was looking at the demos on the site and realized that they did not explain how to add something like a tool bar with an extension. I am lost, more or less. So I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what to do.

btw- the news ticker will eventually connect to a server via ajax

Comment: We've developed something similar. Perhaps you want to take a look. www.cherryfeed.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily use jQuery plugin like the above.

Simply add its javascript code and css as resources and then load it from the extension code itself.

I really recommend taking a look at this Demo App:
http://crossrider.com/apps/9773/ide

You will see exactly what is needed to be done in order to pull it off.

Comment: Demo app url is dead.